# how to keep selected items in temporary memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, ext.net

i want tot add items from gridview temporary memory before clicking save button. Not add database. User add green right arrow. i am using Ext.NET

Add to cart   (memory showing gridview)
Add to cart   (memory showing gridview)
Add to cart   (memory showing gridview)

And then save button to DB

Comment: Can't you use a **Session** ??

Comment: it is a mvc application.

Comment: So whats the matter with that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help you use Session in MVC app, Try this in global.asax:

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("superadmin", user);
}
```

Then in any of your controller:

```
user = HttpContext.Session["superadmin"];
```

Answer came from here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1622898.aspx/1?MVC+amp+Session+Variables

Answer (score 0):

You can either keep the data for the reqeust in the SQL database or use some sort of private static `Dictionary<Request, Cart>`.